# Should I use worker threads for sending more than 5000 HTTP requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, node-worker-threads

If I want to send messages to more than 5000 users in Node.js, which takes a long time, and I don't want it to be render blocking, is "Worker threads" what I need?

The documentation says:

> Workers (threads) are useful for performing CPU-intensive JavaScript operations. They do not help much with I/O-intensive work. The Node.js built-in asynchronous I/O operations are more efficient than Workers can be.

What is the "Node.js built-in asynchronous I/O operations" it is referring to?

I need to loop like more than 5000 contacts:

- store a new row in the database for each contact.
- send a message with an [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) HTTP request to an external API for each contact.

Is this considered as an "I/O operation"?

Comment: Do remember that threading only helps if you are CPU-bound.  It will not help at all if you are network-limited.  If you're sending email, how is that an HTTP request?

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, it is not sending an email, it is sending the same chat message to multiple contacts(chat users) by calling an api with axios

Comment: Writing to a database and making an HTTP request are definitely I/O operations.  Both of them can block.

Comment: "Node.js built-in asynchronous I/O operations" refers to [all the usual IO methods that aren't `Sync` versions](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking), either the Promise or callback style. This also includes the functions you would be calling from the `http` or `net` modules (or that Axios would be calling under the hood). You could scale out workers, but if you spin out 5000+ of them you'll run into resource utilization problems. How about partitioning the list and using some set max number of workers to handle one subset of the list? Or looking into a messaging queue?

Comment: I see, I just dont want sending `5000+` messages to be blocking, but the doc says: `Workers (threads) are useful for performing CPU-intensive JavaScript operations. They do not help much with I/O-intensive work.` so does that mean I should not use `workers thread`? is there a better alternative so it wont be render blocking?

Comment: Does the external API enforce rate limiting?  Does it possibly support bulk operations?

Comment: @phatfingers hi,it is actually a whatsapp meta api, I am doing calling its api with axios to send messages

Comment: "*I dont want it to be render blocking*" - what does your nodejs render?

Answer (score 1):

When using third-party APIs with rate-limiting, I like to pace my asynchronous requests to match their rate limits.  The number of concurrent requests will vary based on latency, but it shouldn't ever be enough to overtax your resources.

```
rateLimiter = {
    paces: {'myList':13},
    starts: {},
    sleep: function(ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)) },
    pace: async function(label) {
            if (this.starts[label]) {
                    let remainingTime=this.paces[label] + this.starts[label] - new Date().getTime();
                    if (remainingTime > 0) await this.sleep(remainingTime);
            }
            this.starts[label]=new Date().getTime();
    }
};

async function processList(myList) {
   for (const member of myList) {
      await rateLimiter.pace('myList');
      APICall(member).then(/* handle it */);
   }
}
```

Comment: Meta Cloud API has a default rate limit of 80 requests/sec (capable of higher rates if you arrange it with them).  `1000ms per 80 req = 12.5ms per req`, which I rounded up to 13ms in the example.

Comment: During the frequent non-blocking `rateLimiter.pace` gaps, your event loop will have plenty of opportunities to handle render operations.

Comment: Hi, are you using this npm package for `rateLimiter`? https://github.com/tj/node-ratelimiter

Comment: @yeln No, the node-ratelimiter package appears to be for rate-limiting requests arriving to your own service.  I created the object in the code above for pacing outbound requests to services that enforce rate-limiting.  It doesn't require any external packages.